# GameAnalytics Progressions No Data

Tags: analytics, unity-game-engine, gameanalytics

I can't view progression data in GameAnalytics Progressions panel. I receive a progression event in Live Feed containing the correct data but progressions panel is empty. I have no problems with other data, design events etc all fine. I'm using Unity 5 and in the console I get this message when sending progression:

addProgressionEvent(1,Level,1,live)

Here is my code line, runs once each level.

```
GameAnalytics.NewProgressionEvent(GAProgressionStatus.Start , "Level" , cur_lvl.ToString() , "live");
```

*cur_lvl*  is the current level index.

Anything I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1):

I should see them after 00.00 GMT.

In the docs you can find that datas remain in live feed all the day long, then at 00.00 GMT they are processed and become available for your dashboard, funnels etc